# What does "afford" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

Extract:

When you entered the world of mass media, you personally and professionally have to accept the scrutiny that comes with the territory, instead of **affording** self pity and accusing your viewers obsessed; words from someone who forced herself into monarchy which is the national institution but suing the press for leaked letters? Stop calling kettles black, or in your case, grey.

Comment: Loosely, it's [***afford*** = *to furnish; supply; to be capable of yielding or providing; to give or confer upon*.](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/affording) But personally I think your example is effectively a "misuse" from a writer who's unsuccessfully trying to convey gravitas and/or erudition. He should just have used ***giving in to*** rather than ***affording***. This is *especially* noticeable because he's mixing the high formal register of "afford" (slightly misused anyway) with that "informal, chatty" business about pots and kettles.

Comment: You haven't given us the source, but I'm inclined to think this subtle misuse would only be likely to have come from a relatively skilled non-native speaker. Who knows just enough to think that "afford" *might* be capable of being used like this, but doesn't know enough to realise that it's an outmoded usage in the first place (and it doesn't *quite* work semantically anyway).

Comment: Source of extract please

Answer (score 1):

"Afford", here, means "to allow" to "to give".

Comment: It's true this is the relevant definition of "afford" for the cited context. But I think what the writer actually *means* is "give **in to** [self-pity]" (*let oneself be **overcome** by self-pity*, not ***lead to** self-pity*).